# How do you check if the user input is a single Char

Tags: java, input, char, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a program where if the user enters a single character, the program displays True on screen, otherwise if multiple characters are entered it prints False.

```
public class FinalExamTakeHome8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Enter an item");
            if (kbd.hasNextInt() || kbd.hasNextChar() || kbd.hasNextDouble()) {
                System.out.println("True");
            } else {
                System.out.println("False");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try checking to see if there is *more than one* character that can be read (perhaps by trying to do so), and inverting the logic? Also: you should make sure you understand how the `Scanner` class interacts with the line buffering of standard input.

Comment: `String input = kbd.nextLine(); System.out.println(input.matches(".{1}"));`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) method to read the user input, regardless of being one or more characters. Then, once you've acquired the text, check whether its length is equals to 1 or not.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Enter an item");
        String input = kbd.nextLine();
        if (input.length() == 1) {
            System.out.println("True");
        } else {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `scanner.nextLine()` method to get the string, then just use the `length()` method to measure the size.

```
String line = kbd.nextLine();
System.out.println(line.length()==1);
```

Because the comparison will result in a Boolean value you can just print it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no dedicated API to check if the user has entered a single character, but can make use of Regex. I have tested it and is working perfectly fine for your use case.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Enter an item");
        if (kbd.hasNextInt() || kbd.hasNext("^[a-zA-Z]") || kbd.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println("True");
        } else {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
    }
}
```